# Yocto/Wic reproducible build of partition

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I am using RAUC updating framework and have A/B partition scheme, I am generating partitions by using .wks file and wic rootfs plugin. I am using adaptive updates and want to use install-same parameter to be able to skip slots if the checksum of update is equal of checksum of partition on installed system.The issue is that the generated ext4 partitions might have files in different order which causes the checksum of the partition always be different even though the content in partition is same as before. I compared the partitions of builds by 7z utility and even though the content is same the order of files isnt.

Is there any way to force Wic or Yocto to build the partition in the specific order? So I would get the same order of files in partition and same checksum when there is no change.

I read guides of reproducible builds for Yocto but they all seem to be focused on the package level and not on the actual file order level in partition.